# Hyperlink not working in jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, tabs

I have the following code: http://pastebin.com/gg4kgGKz

On line 240 of the pastebin code, I have tried to add a hyperlink in one of the list items. However, this does not open the URL, but only closes the tab.

Why is this?

Is there something obvious I've done wrong?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 94 `e.preventDefault();` means that the href doesnt trigger, hence not loading google.

Remove this and it works fine, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/NZFSh/)

Comment: @mcgarriers youre more than welcome. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

before binding tabs try to write something like

`$('a.selector').click(function () { location.href = $(this).attr('href') })`

Comment: Many thanks, Simon. Alex below has provided a very simple fix to this. I'm not hot with Javascript so really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the line 94:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

prevents link opening

Comment: Many thanks, Voooza. Alex replied with the exact same answer and it works perfectly. Thank you!!!